# How to set Button.Style to x:Static resource from code behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I need to call static resource for button style in code-behind using C#

This is my Button in XAML:

```
<Button Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,0,0,0" Name="btnlogin" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Grid.Row="6" BorderThickness="0" 
        MouseEnter="btnlogin_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnlogin_MouseLeave" 
        BorderBrush="Transparent" 
        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BaccaratDealerInterfaceWPF;component/Images/Login_Button_Normal.png" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

I need to set this `Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"`  to `btnlogin.Style` property in code behind C#.

I've tried

```
 Style style = this.FindResource("{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}") as Style;
 btnlogin.Style = style;
```

Comment: Please show how your ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey is declared, but if you have resource with x:Key="MyStyle" then to use it you should do: this.FindResource("MyStyle")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
this.FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey);
```

Here's the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.buttonstylekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for this style and how to access it in both:

- Code behind  `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`
- XAML         `<object property="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}"/>`